# Button on click is not working

Tags: html, asp.net

I am working on a registration page I took a header as a user control page and I am calling that header user control in my master page. In the header there is a login option and in that option I am calling a div for login and signup as shown below.

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 text-center cb">
  <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="colorr">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <br>Login
  </a>
</div>
```

Now I want to registration on the button on click but the problem is its not fire to the code behind on button click. Can you please help me out?

```
<asp:Button ID="btnprocced1" class="btn btn-primary jk" runat="server" 
            Text="procced" OnClick="btnprocced1_Click" />
```

Comment: What happens when you click the button? Do you see any errors in your JavaScript console in your browser's developer tools?

Comment: Have you defined 'btnprocced1_Click' in your code behind file.

Comment: No error has found. And I defined 'bunproccd1_Click' in my code behind. And it was auto created after double click on button.

Comment: Post full code.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the code behind class has a method:

```
protected void btnprocced1_Click(object sender, EventArgs args) 
{
  // ... your logic here ...
}
```

The resulting page class will inherit from this code behind class.
Therefore will need to have access to this method, by using protected.

Comment: I have already use it in my code behind. But still its not working.

Comment: Then check if the page is inheriting from that class and actually referencing the .cs file like - `<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="pageexample.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyCodeBehindCS" %>`